# upsizing ms access 2007 db to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i keep getting an error:

The upsizing wizard does not work with this version of SQL Server to which your access project is connected.

has anyone else seen this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another version of the Upsizing Wizard: [Migrating to SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx)

It's called the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA Access) and you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=133b59c2-c89c-4641-bebb-6d04476ec1ba&DisplayLang=en).

Comment: Technically speaking that's not a newer version although I've heard it's better.  It's a totally different product created by the SQL Server produt group while the Upsizing w=Wizard is produced by the Access product group.

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) 2005 for Access is a tool for migrating databases from Microsoft Access to Microsoft SQL Server 2005."  It does not support SQL Server 2008!

Comment: I was referring to your second link (download here)... take a look!  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4ECD1E67-C64E-49E6-821E-C4D83D9D5FED&displaylang=en

Comment: @ jinsungy: Thanks. I've updated. A comment would have been sufficient without the downvote to get me to change it! But thanks anyway.

Comment: @mitch, downvote removed.. i felt it was necessary since i downloaded/installed/ran the tool for 2005 !

Comment: @jinsungy: apologies for any time you wasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBWScript](http://dbweigher.com/dbwscript.php) to generate sql scripts, such as CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Care to explain how this would be better than using SSMA?

Comment: It isn't better, in my opinion.  It is just another option.